# NavigationBar translucent changes UITextView text position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextView that is positioning its content at the wrong position. As soon as I enter text, the text becomes invisible, and then jumps to the correct position shortly after (almost correct position, slightly lower than what I expected).

When View Debugging I can see that the _UITextContainerView has the wrong position.

What is strange is when I set my NavigationBar appearance to NO,
all works as expected, no problem at all.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.translucent = YES;
```

I have to set my mainView's bound as such else it is not below the 
"NavigationBar"

```
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent) {
        [[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:64]];
    } else {
        [[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0]];
    }
```

Before I enter text:
[image]

After Text is entered, the _UITextContainerView moves down, you can see
the cursor in the middle of the  "_UITextContainerView" view, a tiny
more vertically shaped rectangle.
[image]

**Just found some more info, that could be related to my problem,
my bounds do not match the frame.** Still not sure how to fix this.
I Think this is related, the distance from 4 to -56 = 60, the height of
the NavigationBar.

[image]

**Some more info again:**

I set the font size on the TextField, and after reducing the font size
I notice different results, seem the image.

*Did a test by setting translucent off and all(0,1,2,3 characters) is perfect with reduced font size.*

See the image for font change results:

[image]

```
_textField = [UITextView new];
_textField.bounds = CGRectZero;
_textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
_textField.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
_textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
_textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]; //<< problematic???
```

Comment: Why are you using `self.view` as superview and `toitem:self.view`. But you design look like there is `UITextView` superview not `self.view`. Maybe this issue occurred by constraints. Remove scroll enable for 'UITextView`. (Just for info)

Comment: mainView is inside self.view, the one that StoryBoard gives you. My UITextView is not scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying several things I found that the by adding this
line to my viewDidLoad method solved the problem.

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

A Boolean value that indicates whether the view controller should automatically adjust its scroll view insets.
The **default value of this property is YES**, which lets container view controllers know that they should adjust the scroll view insets of this view controller’s view to account for screen areas consumed by a status bar, search bar, navigation bar, toolbar, or tab bar. **Set this property to NO if your view controller implementation manages its own scroll view inset adjustments.**

Answer (score 0):

If you set navigationBar's translucent to YES, the self.view's origin position will start from the screen's top-left point. If you set NO, it will start from the bar's left-bottom.

Comment: Thanks, for the info. That is why I have different constraints, for when translucent is on or not. Still not sure why my UIText view is changing the way it is.